# Get user email from yahoo when user logs in throuh yahoo app

Tags: php, authentication, yahoo, yahoo-api, hybridauth

Is there is any way to retrieve users email address. I am using hybrid auth. Login works no email address obtained only got access userid , display name & display picture.
Is there any method to get access to email address of user,
Everything is working fine except . The response gives a blank email

```
class Yahoo extends OAuth2
 {
   protected $scope = 'sdct-r';
   protected $apiBaseUrl = 'https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/';
   protected $authorizeUrl = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth';
   protected $accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token';
   protected $apiDocumentation = 'https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/';
   protected $userId = null;
   protected function initialize()
    {
      parent::initialize();
      $this->tokenExchangeHeaders = [
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($this->clientId .  ':' . $this->clientSecret) ]; }
  protected function getCurrentUserId()
     {
      if ($this->userId) {
        return $this->userId;
     }
     $response = $this->apiRequest('me/guid', 'GET', [ 'format' => 'json']);
     $data = new Data\Collection($response);
    if (! $data->filter('guid')->exists('value')) {
        throw new UnexpectedApiResponseException('Provider API returned an unexpected response.');
    }
    return $this->userId =  $data->filter('guid')->get('value');
}
public function getUserProfile()
{
    // Retrieve current user guid if needed
    $this->getCurrentUserId();

    $response = $this->apiRequest('user/'  . $this->userId . '/profile', 'GET', [ 'format' => 'json']);

    $data = new Data\Collection($response);

    if (! $data->exists('profile')) {
        throw new UnexpectedApiResponseException('Provider API returned an unexpected response.');
    }

    $userProfile = new User\Profile();

    $data = $data->filter('profile');

    $userProfile->identifier  = $data->get('guid');
    $userProfile->firstName   = $data->get('givenName');
    $userProfile->lastName    = $data->get('familyName');
    $userProfile->displayName = $data->get('nickname');
    $userProfile->photoURL    = $data->filter('image')->get('imageUrl');
    $userProfile->profileURL  = $data->get('profileUrl');
    $userProfile->language    = $data->get('lang');
    $userProfile->address     = $data->get('location');


    if ('F' == $data->get('gender')) {
        $userProfile->gender = 'female';
    } elseif ('M' == $data->get('gender')) {
        $userProfile->gender = 'male';
    }

    // I ain't getting no emails on my tests. go figures..
    foreach ($data->filter('emails')->toArray() as $item) {
        if ($item->primary) {
          $userProfile->email         = $item->handle;
          $userProfile->emailVerified = $item->handle;
        }
    }

    return $userProfile;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [Yahoo guide](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/decode_id_token.html?guce_referrer=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&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAD2RHKcxW0Q-ka0V3cfDrUYHB8ryQ94wvMXuQq_p479MQM8VljyZnS71HVN4-y0Fzpyy6EWDkjt9unr07M71pZ5A5duu9gqNGU5oUk-aGnWvRXn7cp51aLXbT2A4GbmndDA1MGmd5ooNJy8nToyR0gyisIkpP_E13qrj52yV1ppL&guccounter=1#additional-claims):

> The extended profile scope sdpp-w, in addition to the Claims given
>   above, also returns the following Claims:
>
> email - the email ID of the user
>   email_verified - the Boolean flag letting Clients know if the given email address has been verified by Yahoo.

Please upgrade Hybridauth to [3.0-rc.10](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/releases/tag/v3.0.0-rc.10) which is fixed that issue for Yahoo provider.

See original PR with fix: https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/pull/986